# whitelist_classes error when running rspec with ruby 2.6.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.6

When I upgraded from `ruby 2.5.7` to `ruby 2.6.5` with a `rails 6.0.2` app, then all the rspec tests fail. An example error is

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/account_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

ArgumentError:
  unknown keywords: whitelist_classes, whitelist_symbols
# ./config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
# ./config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
# ./config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/models/account_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
```

Line 7 of `application.rb` is

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

I suspect I need to upgrade one or more of the gems. How do I fix this?

Comment: What's on line 7 of `config/application.rb` and what's it supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is there's a call to `Psych.safe_load` somewhere. Its interface changed between [2.5.7](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.7/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-safe_load) and [2.6.5](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-safe_load). 2.5.7 takes `whitelist_classes` and `whitelist_symbols` as keyword arguments but 2.6.5 has changed them to `permitted_classes` and `permitted_symbols` breaking the interface.

It's possible you need to upgrade `Bundler` or another gem which uses `Psych`. You can try searching your gem sources for `whitelist_classes`. If you use RVM that will be `$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/`.